# Anaconda is not responding

Tags: python, anaconda

I am not able to open up Anaconda Navigator after updating all the packages. When I click Anaconda I get nothing. It is neither responding or giving me an error.

Thank you in advance.

Anaconda or Miniconda version:
conda 4.5.12

Operating System:
MacOs Mojave Version 10.14.2

[image: conda info]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try update Navigator:

```
$ conda update conda
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda update navigator-updater
```

If that does not work, you can reset then update

```
$ anaconda-navigator --reset
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda update navigator-updater
```

If nothing help, you can revert to restore root environment to its state after first installation

```
$ conda install --rev 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I use "$ anaconda-navigator --reset" I receive "Segmentation fault: 11" Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Updating navigator did the trick for me. Life saver :)

Comment: $ anaconda-navigator --reset worked for me.