# My anaconda-navigator just won't launch.(windows 10),even after updating and reinstalling

Tags: python, anaconda

Whenever I write `anaconda-navigator` command in Anaconda prompt I get the following output:

> Warning: `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` is deprecated. Instead, use:
>
> `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` to enable platform plugin controlled
>   per-screen factors.
>
> `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` to set per-screen
>   factors.
>
> `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` to set the application global scale
>   factor.

I am able to use Jupyter Notebook and Spyder by using Anaconda Prompt. But I want my anaconda navigator to open. Please Note that I have already used the following commands:

```
conda update
conda update anaconda-navigator
pip install pyqt5
```

Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898205/anaconda-is-not-responding)

Answer (score 1):

My anaconda also did not start. Trying to run the conda update conda which was indicated elsewhere as a solution gave me errors. The error messages referred to ssl. That seemed the real issue, which pointed me to 
copying these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs:
libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*
This did the trick. Now Anaconda navigator starts.
Kris