# Anaconda Navigator Not Launching

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

I am **not** able to launch **Anaconda Navigator** even after **updating** all the packages. When I click the Anaconda Navigator icon or type `anaconda-navigator` in anaconda prompt, it just shows initializing but doesn't launch. It is neither launching or giving me an error.

I've also tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898205/anaconda-is-not-responding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885228/13254080) and also these GitHub issues - [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1581) and [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9916) and the problem still persists.

**SPECS**:

**OS**: Windows 11 Pro

**Conda version**: conda 4.13.0

**Python version**: Python 3.9.12

**conda info**

> ```
>  active environment : base
> active env location : C:\Users\23481\anaconda3
>         shell level : 1
>    user config file : C:\Users\23481\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\23481\.condarc
>       conda version : 4.13.0
> conda-build version : 3.21.9
>      python version : 3.9.12.final.0
>    virtual packages : __win=0=0
>                       __archspec=1=x86_64
>    base environment : C:\Users\23481\anaconda3  (writable)
>   conda av data dir : C:\Users\23481\anaconda3\etc\conda   conda av metadata url : None
>        channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>       package cache : C:\Users\23481\anaconda3\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\23481\.conda\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\23481\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
>    envs directories : C:\Users\23481\anaconda3\envs
>                       C:\Users\23481\.conda\envs
>                       C:\Users\23481\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
>            platform : win-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.12 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22000
>       administrator : False
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False
> ```

I also noticed that if I try launching anaconda-navigator **with** wifi connection, it doesn't launch as described above but I get this error if I try launching **without** wifi

> (base) C:\Users\23481>anaconda-navigator
> 2022-07-27 15:46:13,698 - ERROR ads._log_errors:22
> Tried to load advertisement data from https://www.anaconda.com/api/navigator. URL is not reachable
>
> 2022-07-27 15:46:13,698 - ERROR ads._log_errors:22
> Tried to load advertisement data from https://www.anaconda.com/api/navigator. URL is not reachable
>
> <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
> <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
> <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
> <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
> <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed><urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, can you try

```
conda clean --packages && conda clean --all && conda update --all
```

Fixed it for me, referring to the open issue [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6706#issuecomment-468081643).

Comment: Thanks but the problem still persists. I'm still unable to launch anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deleting the .condarc file located at C:\Users... And then restarting my PC

Answer (score 0):

Runing the Commands Ahana Deb suggested resolved it for me, in the following sequence:

```
conda clean --packages
conda clean --all
conda update --all
```

[as shown in the image][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEev1.png

After update completed, I ran anaconda-navigator.exe, issue resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer is the same as (or very similar to) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73302515). It would be better to upvote that answer instead of posting it again. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers that helped you.